# open(image_path, "rb") File Not Found Error in Phyton?

Tags: python

I just downloaded python and I'm trying to apply an already working python project. I want to get encrypted files.
I tried but don't know my mistakes and don't know how to express so I will leave photos and links below. Thanks in advance.

https://github.com/kamicater/LG-Gallery-Decryptor

```js
# get strings from the file header
    lgeflock, iv, imagestartbyte = get_lgeflock_iv_imagestart(image_path_encrypted)
    print("lgeflock:", lgeflock.decode('utf-8'))
    
    # iv is stored as byte array with length of 16 bytes
    # iv_hex is stored as hex string with length of 32 chars
    iv_hex = binascii.hexlify(bytearray(iv))
    print("iv:", iv_hex)

    # open encrypted image as bytes
    cipher_file = open(image_path_encrypted, "rb")
    # skip header and iv to image start
    cipher_file.seek(imagestartbyte)
    # read from seek to end
    cipher_body = cipher_file.read()
    cipher_file.close()
    print("File information read successfully")
```

```css
def get_lgeflock_iv_imagestart(image_path):

    # open encrypted image as bytes
    cipher_file = open(image_path, "rb")
    cipher_header = cipher_file.read(1024) # read only first 1 KB
    cipher_file.close()

    # define regex search strings
    lgeflock_searchstring = b'lge/flock(L[0-9\-_]+@lge.com)'
    lgeid_searchstring = b'LGEID2.+\r\n'

    # look up lgeflock:
    re_lgeflock = re.compile(lgeflock_searchstring)
    result_lgeflock = re_lgeflock.search(cipher_header)
    lgeflock = result_lgeflock.group(1)
```

```html
python decryptlg.py encrypted/njjjAV.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/OVOmX4.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/photo_1471713808979.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/photo_1471815529893.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/photo_1471815561014.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/PnaXJ5.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/qjnjnd.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/r66EPz.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/VID-20170122-WA0000.mp4.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/VID-20170125-WA0003.mp4.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/VID-20170514-WA0001.mp4.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/VP0WMV.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/VP8QZB.jpg.dm
python decryptlg.py encrypted/VPP8jV.jpg.dm
```

Comment: Please add your troublesome code to the question - images are not acceptable. And it's Python - not phyton

Comment: I just added as you said.Pardon me, I am new here

Comment: Even if you are not experienced with Python, surely you can see what "File Not Found" means.  The code expects you to create a folder called "encrypted" that holds the encrypted images.  You can change that in the source, if you want.

Comment: I can't open also by changing the source. the python project that I try to apply will let me    open those. except this I could not find any other methods. It was encrypted by Lg with  AES128CBC and .dm extension. Maybe should I install  something to add python to overcome image_path issue?

Comment: What command are you executing, exactly, and where are the files located?  You do not need another module.  You need to know how to use the module you have.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just added two codes that I take error which is  cipher_file = open(image_path, "rb") and lgeflock, iv, imagestartbyte = get_lgeflock_iv_imagestart(image_path_encrypted)

Comment: I typed all files in notepad++ and made it work as .bat extension

Comment: You are adding the `encrypted/` prefix, but the code in the repository ADDS that.  If you change `encrypt_dir = './encrypted'` to `encrypt_dir = ''`, it should work.

Comment: wow.Just wow. I don't know how to thanks right now. I am so happy. I appreciate Tim. You made my day.